# app.component.ts is not in project defined by tsconfig.json

Tags: netbeans, angular, typescript

So I get this error:

> File C:/wamp/www/angular2_demo/GiphySearch/src/app/**app.component.ts** **is
>   not in project defined by**
>   C:/wamp/www/angular2_demo/GiphySearch/e2e/**tsconfig.json**

my folder structure is

```
/
/e2e/tsconfig.json
/src
(others)
```

tsconfig.js has this content

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "mapRoot": "",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "sourceRoot": "/",
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

I tried changing `rootDir` or `sourceRoot` to be defines either as `../` or `../src` or `/src` but nothing worked. How should be properly configured?

Comment: have you tried `./src`? My angular-cli generated tsconfig lives inside /src and only contains `"mapRoot": "./"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined on tsconfig.json [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html):

> The presence of a tsconfig.json file in a directory indicates that the directory is the root of a TypeScript project.

You have your `tsconfig.json` in your e2e directory, not in the src directory, where it should be according to the above link.

I also noticed that you have `"sourceRoot": "/",` would changing it to `./` help?

Comment: Not sure why the angular-cli generated in the e2e folder. I even don't understand what's that folder is about.

Answer (score 2):

The NetBeans project is probably set up to index the whole ng2-cli directory as a single source root, which breaks this Plug-in because there are multiple tsconfig.json files under it (one in src/ and one in e2e/).

In the project properties, under the "Sources" category, set the "Site Root Folder" and "Source Folder" to src. (You can also set "Selenium Tests Folder" to e2e if you want to edit that too).

Comment: Thx! This is the correct answer for projects involving several tsconfig files in them. Then configuration files don't seem to be reachable from the Projects tab anymore, so they have to be accessed via the Files tab (Windows > Files).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I replace the `"outDir": "."` for `"outDir": ""`.

This is my current `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "",  
        "rootDir": "./_src/",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "include" : [
        "_src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks I had similar issue I just added the exclude and compileOnSave and it began working properly !!!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out! This works for me.

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "files": [
      "../src/app/app.component.ts",
      "../src/app/app.component.spec.ts",
      "../src/app/app.module.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: yes, its working can u explain the what exactly u r doing.